# How do i prioritize my "OR" condition in regex. I'm fairly new to coding

Tags: regex

there can be two cases from where i'll need to capture data.

1. Incoming this is a test string
2. this is a test string

I only want to capture "this is a test string".

The regex i wrote is:

```
((?<=Incoming)(?:\s+[A-Za-z-]+)+)|(?:[A-Za-z-]+\s+)
```

The regex works fine without the OR condition for prob statement 1. But as soon as i add the OR condition, the entire string "1" gets captured instead of "this is a test string".

Is there anyway to give priority to the first part of regex? Like i want the first regex to test first and if there is no match, go to second regex.

Thanks

Comment: See a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41011123/3832970).

Comment: Also, a PCRE solution - https://regex101.com/r/TvVa3U/1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to give priority for a regex pattern over another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011010/how-to-give-priority-for-a-regex-pattern-over-another)

Answer (score 0):

If you only use the first part, the match can only start after encountering `Incoming` to the left. If you add the alternation, the second part can and will match the first word.

If you don't want to match `Incoming` but do want to match all the other words, you could use a negative lookahead.

Note that `\s` could also match a newline so I have used a space in the demo.

```
(?<!\S)(?!Incoming\s)[A-Za-z-]+(?:\s+(?!Incoming)[A-Za-z-]+)*
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the left
- `(?!Incoming\s)` Assert what is directly on the right is not Incoming and a whitespace char
- `[A-Za-z-]+` Match 1+ times a char A-Za-z or `-`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+(?!Incoming)` Match 1+ whitespace chars and check what is on the right is not Incoming
- `[A-Za-z-]+` Match 1+ times a char A-Za-z or `-`
- `)*` Close group and repeat 1+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JCCTxZ/1)