# How to use regex in BS4 `find_all` to return matched items with pattern priority?

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have the following regex expression:

```
import re

re.compile('|'.join([pattern1, pattern2, pattern3]))
```

I would like it to work in the following way:

- Try to match only `pattern1`; if matched - stop; else - proceed.
- Try to match only `pattern2`; if matched - stop; else - proceed.
- Try to match only `pattern3`; stop.

However currently it matches all of them.

I found this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41011010/how-to-give-priority-for-a-regex-pattern-over-another), which I thought answers my question, but adding `flags=re.I` does not fix my issue, since my result does not change.

How is this possible (if at all)?

A reproducible example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

xml_doc = """
    <m3_commodity_group commodity3="Oilseeds"><m3_year_group_Collection><m3_year_group market_year3="2011/12"><m3_month_group_Collection><m3_month_group forecast_month3=""><m3_attribute_group_Collection><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Output"><Textbox40><Cell cell_value3="353.93"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Total
    Supply"><Textbox40><Cell cell_value3="429.49"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Trade"><Textbox40><Cell cell_value3="73.59"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Total
    Use  2/"><Textbox40><Cell cell_value3="345.49"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Ending
    Stocks"><Textbox40><Cell cell_value3="59.03"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group></m3_attribute_group_Collection><m3_value_group_Collection><m3_value_group><m3_attribute_group_Collection><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Output"><Textbox40><Cell Textbox44="filler"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Total
    Supply"><Textbox40><Cell Textbox44="filler"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Trade"><Textbox40><Cell Textbox44="filler"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Total
    Use  2/"><Textbox40><Cell Textbox44="filler"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group><m3_attribute_group attribute3="Ending
    Stocks"><Textbox40><Cell Textbox44="filler"/></Textbox40></m3_attribute_group></m3_attribute_group_Collection></m3_value_group></m3_value_group_Collection></m3_month_group></m3_month_group_Collection></m3_year_group></m3_year_group_Collection></m3_commodity_group>
    """

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_doc, "xml")

# This gives 11 vales.
len(soup.find_all(re.compile('|'.join([
    r'^m[0-9]_commodity_group$',r'^m[0-9]_region_group$',r'^m[0-9]_attribute_group$'
]), flags=re.I)))

# This gives 1 value <-- It's what I want, but I want to achieve it with the regex from above (which would work for other texts)
len(soup.find_all(re.compile('|'.join([
    r'^m[0-9]_commodity_group$'
]), flags=re.I)))

# This gives 10 values, which in this example I'd like to be ignored, since the first regex already gave results.
len(soup.find_all(re.compile('|'.join([
    r'^m[0-9]_attribute_group$'
]), flags=re.I)))
```

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: Sure, one moment and I will try to give a reproducible example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could restructure your search:

```
patterns = [r'^m[0-9]_commodity_group$',r'^m[0-9]_region_group$',r'^m[0-9]_attribute_group$']
for pattern in patterns:
    result = soup.find_all(re.compile(pattern, flags=re.I))
    if result:
        break  # Stop after the first time you found a match
else:
    result = None  # When there never was a match
```

That might be more reabable than regex magic. If you will be executing this a lot, you might want to pre-compile your regexes once instead of at every loop iteration.

Comment: Sure, that's a valid option I can do. I was wondering as well whether there is a more elegant/native way to achieve as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of compiling all the regex's together you could iterate through the list with a for loop, and breaking if you find a match.

```
regexList = ['[abc]', '[def]', '[ghi]']
text = input()
for r in regexList:
    mo = re.findall(r, text)
    if mo:
        break
```

If you only want to find 1 result from the regex, then you can use the `search` function in the `re` python package. This package is built in to the standard python libraries.

```
regexList = ['[abc]', '[def]', '[ghi]']
text = input()
for r in regexList:
    mo = re.search(r, text)
    if mo:
        break
```